# Re-scale ratings out of ten to be more representative

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I'm building personal a movie rating matrix for fun in Excel. I rate movies based on many criteria (currently 11) from 0 to 10 and this eventually gives me a final score for the movie based on the average of all the criteria (some criteria can be skipped but I ignore these blanks).

The problem is that I unconsciously rate all the movies I watch within roughly the same interval. I rarely have a movie below 5.5 and rarely have a movie above 9. So I would like to re-scale my ratings to spread the results a bit more on my scale of 0 to 10.

I tried using the Z-Score, which is already better, but it's hard to have an idea of what the number means at first glance. Is there a way to translate this Z-Score on a scale of 0 to 10, somehow? Or even just use another formula?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to pick a different method for calculating the final score than averaging them, depending on your features. But theres an infinite number of maps that will take your features and give a score between 0 and 10.

Comment: @Batman you are probably right. What other method could I use to calculate the final score?